# Why can't my mysql start after modification datadir?

Tags: 20.04, mysql, 22.04, apparmor

### question

**os**:ubuntu 20.04/22.04（have tried）
**mysql**: mysql8
**disk**: mechanical hard drive

Modifying the storage path mysql will not start.
I have followed the instructions on the internet countless times, but ultimately failed.
Both return the following：

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysql
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.
```

### My operation：

```
    1  sudo apt update
    2  sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
    3  sudo grep -R --color datadir /etc/mysql/*
    4  sudo lsblk | grep disk
    5  sudo fdisk /dev/sdd
    6  sudo lsblk | grep disk
    7  sudo fdisk /dev/sdd
    8  sudo mkfs.ext4 -L db_data /dev/sdd1
    9  sudo mkdir /db
   10  sudo nano /etc/fstab
   11  df -h /db
   12  sudo chown mysql:mysql /db
   13  sudo systemctl stop mysql
   14  sudo rsync -avzh /var/lib/mysql/ /db
   15  sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias
   16  sudo systemctl restart apparmor
   17  sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
   18  sudo systemctl start mysql
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ydYZ.png)

### The log

##### /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
2022-05-02T22:51:37.712572Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /db/ is case insensitive
2022-05-02T22:51:37.713036Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-05-02T22:51:37.713175Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu4)  (Ubuntu).
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-05-02T22:51:38.252419Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /db/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-05-02T22:51:38.252459Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu4) starting as process 10542
2022-05-02T22:51:38.253869Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /db/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-05-02T22:51:38.253874Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /db/ is case insensitive
2022-05-02T22:51:38.254172Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-05-02T22:51:38.254252Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu4)  (Ubuntu).
```

##### sudo systemctl status mysql

```
× mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enable>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-05-02 22:51:38 UTC; 34min ago
    Process: 10533 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited,>
    Process: 10542 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 10542 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 13 (权限不够)
        CPU: 268ms

5月 02 22:51:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart count>
5月 02 22:51:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
5月 02 22:51:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
5月 02 22:51:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
5月 02 22:51:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

### My configuration:

##### `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias`

```
alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /db/,
```

##### `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`(`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` also tried)

```
...
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
datadir = /db
...
```

### Other attempts：

- Mount to `/var/lib/mysql` before installing(**fail**)
- do not modify`datadir` modify other(**success**)

### References：

- [How To Move a MySQL Data Directory to a New Location on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- [How to Change MySQL/MariaDB Data Directory on Ubuntu](https://linuxhint.com/change_mysql_data_directory_ubuntu/)
- [How to change MySQL data directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory)

**Looking forward to your help, thanks！**

Comment: What file system is being used for `/db`? If you're using Ext4 or ZFS, which flags were used during the creation of the file system? 

Comment: @matigo Using Ext4, what is flags?

Comment: The MySQL log is reporting that your file system is case insensitive, which is uncommon for Ext4 file systems. This is manually specified at the time you create the file system, which has me wondering if there might be other issues that may contribute to the issue. That said, the bulk of the issue is likely AppArmor. Rather than using aliases, it has generally been easier (for me) to change the requisite directories to the configuration for MySQL itself, replacing `/var/lib/mysql` with `/db` (or wherever the data may be stored).

Comment: solved such issue by [disabling mysqld profile in a apparmor](https://askubuntu.com/a/1144525/1607135)